# Postgres - how to manage intensively growing DB

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

I have intensively growing DB, what generates noticeable storage cost (buying new SSDs, increasing backup license etc).
In addition to that bigger and bigger maintenance window is required (to finish backup jobs)

I wonder how you Guys addressing that in your PROD systems ?

My 1st idea was to split biggest tables (and indices) to 'historical' and 'most current' data parts.
Keep 'historical' piece on slower, but less expensive HDDs, but 'most current' on SSDs
Also do not backup 'historical' part until it changes

Thanks to that I can generate some savings (not needed investments in expanding SSDs arrays) and reduce cost of backups (will not be backing up 'historical' piece over and over)
Still Id be able to access to 'historical data', but (I guess a bit slower)

However I have doubts about performance impact and potential consistency breaks
(Performance is key thing in my business)

Do you have any experience in that? Any thoughts / ideas ?

PS> I have PG12, but planning migration to PG14 soon

Comment: If your backups require a maintenance window, you are doing something wrong

Comment: You need a license (and downtime) to back up your data?

Comment: Key things Id like to archive here are costs savings (SSDs..) & performance gain. Backups / maintenance window is less important. Im doing full DB SQL dump - I guess this is what you are pointing as not ideal thing ?

Answer (score 1):

Partition your tables by range. Create an additional tablespace on the slow, cheap storage. Move old partitions to the slow tablespace (and drop partitions with very old data).

You should have partitioned tables from the beginning. To transition, you could create a new partitioned table and define your current table as a partition of it.

Another way to partition an existing table would be to use logical replication for the upgrade and replicate into a partitioned table.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by dropping partitions? Id like still to have access to even very old data. Also I didnt get why I need create new partitioned table. Cant I just split currently existing ?

Comment: You need access to tons of 15 year old data? Ok, it is just unusual. Sure, you can split an existing table if you don't mind days of down time.

Comment: Total DB is ~4T. Top 5 tables = ~50%. From time to time (1-5x a year) I do need access to historical data. those top 5 tables have references (relations) to other tables. 
Can I just 'disconnect' / drop partition with historical data without breaking DB consistency, and just reconnect those when needed ?

Comment: If you use partitioned tables, you won't be able to create the primary and foreign keys you want, and you may have to live without them. In particular, a foreign key pointing to a partitioned table will prevent you from detaching a partition. PostgreSQL doesn't allow you to break consistency.

Comment: I'll survive without detaching. But what I understood from your comments, I can still divide table on smaller 'archive' partitions, treat them as 'locked' / 'read only' -> place on slower/cheaper HDDs. Correct ?

Comment: You cannot divide an existing table into partitions without some major effort; you have to start with a partitioned table. Otherwise yes.

Comment: Oh I didnt know that. So what would be procedure to partition existing table?
Would it be something like this? 
1) switch to maint mode
2) rename table to eg *_old, remove constrains
3) create partitioned table with same structure and name as org one
4) copy data and constrains
5) switch db back to online

Comment: I should have known better than to write an answer to such a generic question. Here is the usual rat's tail of "but how do I" and "but what if". You cannot expect a consulting session in a Q&A forum. Hire a consultant, or do some research yourself.

Comment: @Laurentz - sometime it is better to reply nothing than reply in that way... so handy / useful / helpful advise! Thanks! :[
I like detail discussions because other people can also have some benefits from that.